# omnetpp vector recording on linux and windows

Tags: linux, omnet++

im running an omnet simulation on two platforms:

1. omnetpp 4.4.1 on windows 7
2. omnestpp (dont sure about the version) on VM running linux

i ran the same simulation on both platforms without problems. but, when i added the following lines:

```
**.used*.vector-recording = true
**.Byte Increase Counter.vector-recording = true
**.Timer Increase Counter.vector-recording = true
**.client[*].**.Sent R*.vector-recording = true

**.vector-recording = false
**.scalar-recording = false
```

the vectors: "byte increase counter" and "timer increase counter", werent recorded on the linux.

i have tried to move the .vec files from the windows to the linux, to make sure that the problem is not about reading the vectors.

any ideas why the vectors werent recorded on the linux?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to use spaces in the name of vector.

Comment: thanx, but iv'e tried this already, and it didn't help.
i also have another vecotrs with spaces in their name, and they are recorded successfully.